# Fotos dos usuários não aparecem em navegadores que não estou logado

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, perfil, imagem

Eu fui ver uma resposta em outro computador, e não estava logado, percebi que minha foto é só um óculos voando no meio do além, alguns usuários também ficam assim, porém outros aparece normal.

<kbd>[image: Um óculos no vácuo do tempo e espaço]</kbd>

Isso é um bug ou alguma configuração de privacidade que passou despercebido em minha conta?

Comment: Tentou Crtrl+F5? Aqui acontece as vezes, como no perfil acho que tem um `float:` ou `display: block` na tag `<img>` talvez não apareça aquele quadrado de foto quebrada. No Chrome e Opera aparece normal no momento (usei modo anonimo). Se estiver aparecendo agora, talvez tenha sido um problema de oscilação de internet ou do servidor.

Comment: Não é firewall?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo reproduzir também...

Comment: Aparentemente ocorre nos computadores que estão definidos com o DNS do OpenDNS, porém não posso confirmar isso pois não foi possível reproduzir com 100% de precisão, pode ser um problema apenas local, vou continuar observando.

Comment: Posso afirmar que comigo este problema já aconteceu várias vezes. De vez em quando a foto de alguns usuários não carregam. Ficar dando F5 ou Shift-F5 não resolve, o problema se corrige sozinho alguns minutos mais tarde, e daí em algum outro dia ele volta a acontecer. O comportamento sempre é aleatório, incerto e intermitente, e por isso não dá para reproduzir com nenhum tipo de confiabilidade. Isso tudo me faz acreditar que deve ser algum problema com DNS, roteamento de pacotes, timeouts ou algo a ver com controle de fluxo/congestionamento.